# What does it mean when lower management gets replaced very frequently?

Tags: management, manager, company-culture

I have been working for one company for a bit over a year. The local manager (i.e. local to the city) never lasts more than 1 or 2 months. We are never given a reason why they quit or were fired. This can be a bit of a problem because at minimum each new manager has a different communication style. What does this say about the company?

Comment: Never having a manager that's familiar with your work and accomplishments makes end of year performance and salary discussions more difficult. Make sure you're keeping track of *everything*, not just the big things.

Answer (score 7):

> What does this say about the company?

Impossible to know, we would be guessing.

However, whatever this says about the company and whatever the true reasons where, I am positive that it's no good sign.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, there are two reasons a person leaves: they quit, or they're fired.

Applying that to the situation you've laid out, there's two general possibilities:

- The managers are quitting.  Aka, the jobs stinks so badly that none
  of them are willing to do it for more than a few months.
- The managers are rapidly being fired.  Aka, either there's been a
  string of bad managers or the higher-ups are overly demanding for
  performance that nobody's been able to live up to.

Like DarkCygnus says, it's a bit tough to give a concrete answer when there's not really any info to go off of.